# How to solve triple integral that is broken up into two regions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Integral $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{z^2} \int_{z}^{1} e^y dx\,dy\,dz \,\,+\,\,
 \int_{0}^{1} \int_{z^2}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} e^y dx\,dy\,dz$

I am completely lost..

At first, I tried graphing it, which basically gives a square plus some euler curve on top of the square.

I understand the geometry of this however, I just cannot seem to determine the bounds for each sub-region. If someone can walk me through step by step or just briefly explain, I would very much appreciate it.

For example, I have two graphs:

Graph A - we know that 0 <= y <= z^2 and z <= x <= 1

Graph B - z^2<=y<=1 and root(y) <= x <= 1.

So graph A basically is a square (z, 0), (1,0), (z, z^2), (1, z^2).

Graph B is basically a curve y = x^2 so we have two points, 
(z, x^2) (1, 1)

From here, I honestly don't know how to manipulate the bounds and re-order the integral to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The inner integrals always tell the biggest story because they always give you concrete surfaces involved in the problem. We get

$$y = x^2$$
$$x=1$$
$$z=x$$

for free. Drawing these out we can see that we also get

$$y=0$$
$$z=0$$

Fortunately for us there is an integration order that will give us one integral. To find it, note that

$$0 \leq y \leq x^2$$

since all of the other boundaries are "invisible" to $y$ (i.e. they are parallel to the $y$ axis). We also have that

$$0 \leq z \leq x$$

for the same reason. Then we have

$$I = \int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^{x^2} e^y \:dy \:dz \:dx = \frac{e-3}{2}$$

Comment: Okay. I think just algebraically I understand what you did. Basically, by finding the boundaries for each integral with respect to one variable, you are able to change the order of integration and in this case, the limiting boundaries are with respect to x and you can change the order now to dydzdx. Since by the time we get to dx, we are able to do integration by parts to solve for an integral that contains e to the power of x squared since there is also an x variable multiplied by the e... I dont know why i didnt see this

Comment: Okay so I just finished my practice exam and what I meant to say was, you set all the boundaries with respect to one variable so that the rest can be held as constants. Which means by the time we get to the outer most integral, we can either do u-substitution or integration by parts